# How to put a table inside an inline-block element where cells have a percentage width

Tags: html, css

I want to create a table inside a container which have the css-style "display: inline-block". The table should be as wide as the other content in this box, but not wider. The table in my example have 3 cells. The first cell should be as wide as its inner content. The second one should get 30% (of available width) and the third one should get 70% (of available width).

This works fine for Firefox (this is how it should look like):

[image: This works fine for firefox]

Using the following Markup:

```
<div>
    This text sets the width for the display: inline-block container.<br />
    Table should not get wider than this.
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Small</td>
            <td width="30%">30%</td>
            <td width="70%">70%</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
div { display: inline-block; }
table { width: 100%; }
td { background-color: green; }
```

(Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SuperNova3000/Z7Car/)

Chrome for example will fail using the above example (the table gets a width of 100% + Cellspacings and is wider as the window). In IE10 the table will get 100% (without cellspacings).

Is there any way to accomplish this task? It's NOT a layout for a website, but for a formular container which should be flexible (adding more "Small" rows, having other percentage values). This is a simplified version.

I'm looking for a PLAIN HTML and CSS solution which works in every browser.

Changing the table cells to this:

```
<td width="1">Small</td>
<td>30%</td>
<td>70%</td>
```

creates a layout which respects the "Small" cells. But I cannot see any way to get 30%/70% columns working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Set `box-sizing: border-box;` on the outer div.

Comment: @thebjorn Seems not to change anything? The div has no margin/padding/border.

Comment: Hmm.. seems like a bug in FF. From (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html): "The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box, and the element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box.", so since the div doesn't have a width, the table should take up 30%/70% of the closest containing element that constrains the width (at least that's how I read it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using `div { inline-table }` rather than `div { inline-block }`

See http://jsfiddle.net/Z7Car/3/

Comment: OMG, it CAN'T be that simple... But it seems to work in every modern browser. I never thought about it. In my mind a table must have cells, so a div with inline-table set must have a cell. Working like a charm. I'll accept this answer.